# Gradle new plugin installation

Tags: plugins, build, gradle, build-automation

What should I do to install a plugin into gradle so I can use it in the future builds.

I want to use rpm plugin here: https://github.com/TrigonicSolutions/gradle-rpm-plugin

I tried downloading the project and copying the jar that's there in the %GRADLE_HOME%/lib/plugins, but it doesn't look like it works since

```
apply plugin: 'rpm'
```

fails.

This should probably be easy, but I don't see it in docs or can't really find how to do it. Do I need to run some task to put the jar in the repository of plugins? Any info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a few months old, but figured I would provide an answer for those who browse to this page!

For the specific plugin above (and others, I would imagine), simply download the [source](https://github.com/TrigonicSolutions/gradle-rpm-plugin), then using that source's root folder, run the following task:

gradle install

This should install the plugin for the current user.

Note, if you run some of your gradle scripts using 'sudo' or admin rights, you will have to install the plugin for them as well.